# How to avoid latex longtable using whole width of page?

Tags: longtable

When I use longtable with a small amount of columns it uses whole widht of page to display the table.

This is the result with three columns:

[image]

My aim is to make the table only use an amount of space that is sufficient to fit three columns.Does anyone have an idea about how to do that?

This is de the code I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
    \usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \newcommand{\euro}{€}
    \setmainfont{Calibri Light}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
              unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
              xetex]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            bookmarks=true,
            pdfauthor={test,test,test},
            pdftitle={TEST},
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue,
            linkcolor=blue,
            pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

%%% Use protect on footnotes to avoid problems with footnotes in titles
\let\rmarkdownfootnote\footnote%
\def\footnote{\protect\rmarkdownfootnote}

%%% Change title format to be more compact
\usepackage{titling}

% Create subtitle command for use in maketitle
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{
  \posttitle{
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    }
}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-2em}
  \title{TEST}
  \pretitle{\vspace{\droptitle}\centering\huge}
  \posttitle{\par}
\subtitle{A test document}
  \author{test,test,test}
  \preauthor{\centering\large\emph}
  \postauthor{\par}
  \date{}
  \predate{}\postdate{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{test document}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,skip=2pt,labelsep=space,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\raggedbottom


\begin{document}

\maketitle


\section{start}\label{start}

\hyperref[section]{sec}

\ref{section}

\section{second}\label{second}

\setlongtables{\small
\begin{longtable}{lrrr}\caption{title} \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col1}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col2}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col3}\tabularnewline
\hline
\endfirsthead\caption[]{\em (continued)} \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col1}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col2}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col3}\tabularnewline
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{p{\linewidth}}{note}\tabularnewline
\endfoot
\label{}
1&$  1$&$  1$&$  1$\tabularnewline
2&$  2$&$  2$&$  2$\tabularnewline
3&$  3$&$  3$&$  3$\tabularnewline
4&$  4$&$  4$&$  4$\tabularnewline
5&$  5$&$  5$&$  5$\tabularnewline
6&$  6$&$  6$&$  6$\tabularnewline
7&$  7$&$  7$&$  7$\tabularnewline
8&$  8$&$  8$&$  8$\tabularnewline
9&$  9$&$  9$&$  9$\tabularnewline
10&$ 10$&$ 10$&$ 10$\tabularnewline
11&$ 11$&$ 11$&$ 11$\tabularnewline
12&$ 12$&$ 12$&$ 12$\tabularnewline
13&$ 13$&$ 13$&$ 13$\tabularnewline
14&$ 14$&$ 14$&$ 14$\tabularnewline
15&$ 15$&$ 15$&$ 15$\tabularnewline
16&$ 16$&$ 16$&$ 16$\tabularnewline
17&$ 17$&$ 17$&$ 17$\tabularnewline
18&$ 18$&$ 18$&$ 18$\tabularnewline
19&$ 19$&$ 19$&$ 19$\tabularnewline
20&$ 20$&$ 20$&$ 20$\tabularnewline
21&$ 21$&$ 21$&$ 21$\tabularnewline
22&$ 22$&$ 22$&$ 22$\tabularnewline
23&$ 23$&$ 23$&$ 23$\tabularnewline
24&$ 24$&$ 24$&$ 24$\tabularnewline
25&$ 25$&$ 25$&$ 25$\tabularnewline
26&$ 26$&$ 26$&$ 26$\tabularnewline
27&$ 27$&$ 27$&$ 27$\tabularnewline
28&$ 28$&$ 28$&$ 28$\tabularnewline
29&$ 29$&$ 29$&$ 29$\tabularnewline
30&$ 30$&$ 30$&$ 30$\tabularnewline
31&$ 31$&$ 31$&$ 31$\tabularnewline
32&$ 32$&$ 32$&$ 32$\tabularnewline
33&$ 33$&$ 33$&$ 33$\tabularnewline
34&$ 34$&$ 34$&$ 34$\tabularnewline
35&$ 35$&$ 35$&$ 35$\tabularnewline
36&$ 36$&$ 36$&$ 36$\tabularnewline
37&$ 37$&$ 37$&$ 37$\tabularnewline
38&$ 38$&$ 38$&$ 38$\tabularnewline
39&$ 39$&$ 39$&$ 39$\tabularnewline
40&$ 40$&$ 40$&$ 40$\tabularnewline
41&$ 41$&$ 41$&$ 41$\tabularnewline
42&$ 42$&$ 42$&$ 42$\tabularnewline
43&$ 43$&$ 43$&$ 43$\tabularnewline
44&$ 44$&$ 44$&$ 44$\tabularnewline
45&$ 45$&$ 45$&$ 45$\tabularnewline
46&$ 46$&$ 46$&$ 46$\tabularnewline
47&$ 47$&$ 47$&$ 47$\tabularnewline
48&$ 48$&$ 48$&$ 48$\tabularnewline
49&$ 49$&$ 49$&$ 49$\tabularnewline
50&$ 50$&$ 50$&$ 50$\tabularnewline
51&$ 51$&$ 51$&$ 51$\tabularnewline
52&$ 52$&$ 52$&$ 52$\tabularnewline
53&$ 53$&$ 53$&$ 53$\tabularnewline
54&$ 54$&$ 54$&$ 54$\tabularnewline
55&$ 55$&$ 55$&$ 55$\tabularnewline
56&$ 56$&$ 56$&$ 56$\tabularnewline
57&$ 57$&$ 57$&$ 57$\tabularnewline
58&$ 58$&$ 58$&$ 58$\tabularnewline
59&$ 59$&$ 59$&$ 59$\tabularnewline
60&$ 60$&$ 60$&$ 60$\tabularnewline
61&$ 61$&$ 61$&$ 61$\tabularnewline
62&$ 62$&$ 62$&$ 62$\tabularnewline
63&$ 63$&$ 63$&$ 63$\tabularnewline
64&$ 64$&$ 64$&$ 64$\tabularnewline
65&$ 65$&$ 65$&$ 65$\tabularnewline
66&$ 66$&$ 66$&$ 66$\tabularnewline
67&$ 67$&$ 67$&$ 67$\tabularnewline
68&$ 68$&$ 68$&$ 68$\tabularnewline
69&$ 69$&$ 69$&$ 69$\tabularnewline
70&$ 70$&$ 70$&$ 70$\tabularnewline
71&$ 71$&$ 71$&$ 71$\tabularnewline
72&$ 72$&$ 72$&$ 72$\tabularnewline
73&$ 73$&$ 73$&$ 73$\tabularnewline
74&$ 74$&$ 74$&$ 74$\tabularnewline
75&$ 75$&$ 75$&$ 75$\tabularnewline
76&$ 76$&$ 76$&$ 76$\tabularnewline
77&$ 77$&$ 77$&$ 77$\tabularnewline
78&$ 78$&$ 78$&$ 78$\tabularnewline
79&$ 79$&$ 79$&$ 79$\tabularnewline
80&$ 80$&$ 80$&$ 80$\tabularnewline
81&$ 81$&$ 81$&$ 81$\tabularnewline
82&$ 82$&$ 82$&$ 82$\tabularnewline
83&$ 83$&$ 83$&$ 83$\tabularnewline
84&$ 84$&$ 84$&$ 84$\tabularnewline
85&$ 85$&$ 85$&$ 85$\tabularnewline
86&$ 86$&$ 86$&$ 86$\tabularnewline
87&$ 87$&$ 87$&$ 87$\tabularnewline
88&$ 88$&$ 88$&$ 88$\tabularnewline
89&$ 89$&$ 89$&$ 89$\tabularnewline
90&$ 90$&$ 90$&$ 90$\tabularnewline
91&$ 91$&$ 91$&$ 91$\tabularnewline
92&$ 92$&$ 92$&$ 92$\tabularnewline
93&$ 93$&$ 93$&$ 93$\tabularnewline
94&$ 94$&$ 94$&$ 94$\tabularnewline
95&$ 95$&$ 95$&$ 95$\tabularnewline
96&$ 96$&$ 96$&$ 96$\tabularnewline
97&$ 97$&$ 97$&$ 97$\tabularnewline
98&$ 98$&$ 98$&$ 98$\tabularnewline
99&$ 99$&$ 99$&$ 99$\tabularnewline
100&$100$&$100$&$100$\tabularnewline
101&$101$&$101$&$101$\tabularnewline
102&$102$&$102$&$102$\tabularnewline
103&$103$&$103$&$103$\tabularnewline
104&$104$&$104$&$104$\tabularnewline
105&$105$&$105$&$105$\tabularnewline
106&$106$&$106$&$106$\tabularnewline
107&$107$&$107$&$107$\tabularnewline
108&$108$&$108$&$108$\tabularnewline
109&$109$&$109$&$109$\tabularnewline
110&$110$&$110$&$110$\tabularnewline
111&$111$&$111$&$111$\tabularnewline
112&$112$&$112$&$112$\tabularnewline
113&$113$&$113$&$113$\tabularnewline
114&$114$&$114$&$114$\tabularnewline
115&$115$&$115$&$115$\tabularnewline
116&$116$&$116$&$116$\tabularnewline
117&$117$&$117$&$117$\tabularnewline
118&$118$&$118$&$118$\tabularnewline
119&$119$&$119$&$119$\tabularnewline
120&$120$&$120$&$120$\tabularnewline
121&$121$&$121$&$121$\tabularnewline
122&$122$&$122$&$122$\tabularnewline
123&$123$&$123$&$123$\tabularnewline
124&$124$&$124$&$124$\tabularnewline
125&$125$&$125$&$125$\tabularnewline
126&$126$&$126$&$126$\tabularnewline
127&$127$&$127$&$127$\tabularnewline
128&$128$&$128$&$128$\tabularnewline
129&$129$&$129$&$129$\tabularnewline
130&$130$&$130$&$130$\tabularnewline
131&$131$&$131$&$131$\tabularnewline
132&$132$&$132$&$132$\tabularnewline
133&$133$&$133$&$133$\tabularnewline
134&$134$&$134$&$134$\tabularnewline
135&$135$&$135$&$135$\tabularnewline
136&$136$&$136$&$136$\tabularnewline
137&$137$&$137$&$137$\tabularnewline
138&$138$&$138$&$138$\tabularnewline
139&$139$&$139$&$139$\tabularnewline
140&$140$&$140$&$140$\tabularnewline
141&$141$&$141$&$141$\tabularnewline
142&$142$&$142$&$142$\tabularnewline
143&$143$&$143$&$143$\tabularnewline
144&$144$&$144$&$144$\tabularnewline
145&$145$&$145$&$145$\tabularnewline
146&$146$&$146$&$146$\tabularnewline
147&$147$&$147$&$147$\tabularnewline
148&$148$&$148$&$148$\tabularnewline
149&$149$&$149$&$149$\tabularnewline
150&$150$&$150$&$150$\tabularnewline
151&$151$&$151$&$151$\tabularnewline
152&$152$&$152$&$152$\tabularnewline
153&$153$&$153$&$153$\tabularnewline
154&$154$&$154$&$154$\tabularnewline
155&$155$&$155$&$155$\tabularnewline
156&$156$&$156$&$156$\tabularnewline
157&$157$&$157$&$157$\tabularnewline
158&$158$&$158$&$158$\tabularnewline
159&$159$&$159$&$159$\tabularnewline
160&$160$&$160$&$160$\tabularnewline
161&$161$&$161$&$161$\tabularnewline
162&$162$&$162$&$162$\tabularnewline
163&$163$&$163$&$163$\tabularnewline
164&$164$&$164$&$164$\tabularnewline
165&$165$&$165$&$165$\tabularnewline
166&$166$&$166$&$166$\tabularnewline
167&$167$&$167$&$167$\tabularnewline
168&$168$&$168$&$168$\tabularnewline
169&$169$&$169$&$169$\tabularnewline
170&$170$&$170$&$170$\tabularnewline
171&$171$&$171$&$171$\tabularnewline
172&$172$&$172$&$172$\tabularnewline
173&$173$&$173$&$173$\tabularnewline
174&$174$&$174$&$174$\tabularnewline
175&$175$&$175$&$175$\tabularnewline
176&$176$&$176$&$176$\tabularnewline
177&$177$&$177$&$177$\tabularnewline
178&$178$&$178$&$178$\tabularnewline
179&$179$&$179$&$179$\tabularnewline
180&$180$&$180$&$180$\tabularnewline
181&$181$&$181$&$181$\tabularnewline
182&$182$&$182$&$182$\tabularnewline
183&$183$&$183$&$183$\tabularnewline
184&$184$&$184$&$184$\tabularnewline
185&$185$&$185$&$185$\tabularnewline
186&$186$&$186$&$186$\tabularnewline
187&$187$&$187$&$187$\tabularnewline
188&$188$&$188$&$188$\tabularnewline
189&$189$&$189$&$189$\tabularnewline
190&$190$&$190$&$190$\tabularnewline
191&$191$&$191$&$191$\tabularnewline
192&$192$&$192$&$192$\tabularnewline
193&$193$&$193$&$193$\tabularnewline
194&$194$&$194$&$194$\tabularnewline
195&$195$&$195$&$195$\tabularnewline
196&$196$&$196$&$196$\tabularnewline
197&$197$&$197$&$197$\tabularnewline
198&$198$&$198$&$198$\tabularnewline
199&$199$&$199$&$199$\tabularnewline
200&$200$&$200$&$200$\tabularnewline
201&$201$&$201$&$201$\tabularnewline
202&$202$&$202$&$202$\tabularnewline
203&$203$&$203$&$203$\tabularnewline
204&$204$&$204$&$204$\tabularnewline
205&$205$&$205$&$205$\tabularnewline
206&$206$&$206$&$206$\tabularnewline
207&$207$&$207$&$207$\tabularnewline
208&$208$&$208$&$208$\tabularnewline
209&$209$&$209$&$209$\tabularnewline
210&$210$&$210$&$210$\tabularnewline
211&$211$&$211$&$211$\tabularnewline
212&$212$&$212$&$212$\tabularnewline
213&$213$&$213$&$213$\tabularnewline
214&$214$&$214$&$214$\tabularnewline
215&$215$&$215$&$215$\tabularnewline
216&$216$&$216$&$216$\tabularnewline
217&$217$&$217$&$217$\tabularnewline
218&$218$&$218$&$218$\tabularnewline
219&$219$&$219$&$219$\tabularnewline
220&$220$&$220$&$220$\tabularnewline
221&$221$&$221$&$221$\tabularnewline
222&$222$&$222$&$222$\tabularnewline
223&$223$&$223$&$223$\tabularnewline
224&$224$&$224$&$224$\tabularnewline
225&$225$&$225$&$225$\tabularnewline
226&$226$&$226$&$226$\tabularnewline
227&$227$&$227$&$227$\tabularnewline
228&$228$&$228$&$228$\tabularnewline
229&$229$&$229$&$229$\tabularnewline
230&$230$&$230$&$230$\tabularnewline
231&$231$&$231$&$231$\tabularnewline
232&$232$&$232$&$232$\tabularnewline
233&$233$&$233$&$233$\tabularnewline
234&$234$&$234$&$234$\tabularnewline
235&$235$&$235$&$235$\tabularnewline
236&$236$&$236$&$236$\tabularnewline
237&$237$&$237$&$237$\tabularnewline
238&$238$&$238$&$238$\tabularnewline
239&$239$&$239$&$239$\tabularnewline
240&$240$&$240$&$240$\tabularnewline
241&$241$&$241$&$241$\tabularnewline
242&$242$&$242$&$242$\tabularnewline
243&$243$&$243$&$243$\tabularnewline
244&$244$&$244$&$244$\tabularnewline
245&$245$&$245$&$245$\tabularnewline
246&$246$&$246$&$246$\tabularnewline
247&$247$&$247$&$247$\tabularnewline
248&$248$&$248$&$248$\tabularnewline
249&$249$&$249$&$249$\tabularnewline
250&$250$&$250$&$250$\tabularnewline
251&$251$&$251$&$251$\tabularnewline
252&$252$&$252$&$252$\tabularnewline
253&$253$&$253$&$253$\tabularnewline
254&$254$&$254$&$254$\tabularnewline
255&$255$&$255$&$255$\tabularnewline
256&$256$&$256$&$256$\tabularnewline
257&$257$&$257$&$257$\tabularnewline
258&$258$&$258$&$258$\tabularnewline
259&$259$&$259$&$259$\tabularnewline
260&$260$&$260$&$260$\tabularnewline
261&$261$&$261$&$261$\tabularnewline
262&$262$&$262$&$262$\tabularnewline
263&$263$&$263$&$263$\tabularnewline
264&$264$&$264$&$264$\tabularnewline
265&$265$&$265$&$265$\tabularnewline
266&$266$&$266$&$266$\tabularnewline
267&$267$&$267$&$267$\tabularnewline
268&$268$&$268$&$268$\tabularnewline
269&$269$&$269$&$269$\tabularnewline
270&$270$&$270$&$270$\tabularnewline
271&$271$&$271$&$271$\tabularnewline
272&$272$&$272$&$272$\tabularnewline
273&$273$&$273$&$273$\tabularnewline
274&$274$&$274$&$274$\tabularnewline
275&$275$&$275$&$275$\tabularnewline
276&$276$&$276$&$276$\tabularnewline
277&$277$&$277$&$277$\tabularnewline
278&$278$&$278$&$278$\tabularnewline
279&$279$&$279$&$279$\tabularnewline
280&$280$&$280$&$280$\tabularnewline
281&$281$&$281$&$281$\tabularnewline
282&$282$&$282$&$282$\tabularnewline
283&$283$&$283$&$283$\tabularnewline
284&$284$&$284$&$284$\tabularnewline
285&$285$&$285$&$285$\tabularnewline
286&$286$&$286$&$286$\tabularnewline
287&$287$&$287$&$287$\tabularnewline
288&$288$&$288$&$288$\tabularnewline
289&$289$&$289$&$289$\tabularnewline
290&$290$&$290$&$290$\tabularnewline
291&$291$&$291$&$291$\tabularnewline
292&$292$&$292$&$292$\tabularnewline
293&$293$&$293$&$293$\tabularnewline
294&$294$&$294$&$294$\tabularnewline
295&$295$&$295$&$295$\tabularnewline
296&$296$&$296$&$296$\tabularnewline
297&$297$&$297$&$297$\tabularnewline
298&$298$&$298$&$298$\tabularnewline
299&$299$&$299$&$299$\tabularnewline
300&$300$&$300$&$300$\tabularnewline
301&$301$&$301$&$301$\tabularnewline
302&$302$&$302$&$302$\tabularnewline
303&$303$&$303$&$303$\tabularnewline
304&$304$&$304$&$304$\tabularnewline
305&$305$&$305$&$305$\tabularnewline
306&$306$&$306$&$306$\tabularnewline
307&$307$&$307$&$307$\tabularnewline
308&$308$&$308$&$308$\tabularnewline
309&$309$&$309$&$309$\tabularnewline
310&$310$&$310$&$310$\tabularnewline
311&$311$&$311$&$311$\tabularnewline
312&$312$&$312$&$312$\tabularnewline
313&$313$&$313$&$313$\tabularnewline
314&$314$&$314$&$314$\tabularnewline
315&$315$&$315$&$315$\tabularnewline
316&$316$&$316$&$316$\tabularnewline
317&$317$&$317$&$317$\tabularnewline
318&$318$&$318$&$318$\tabularnewline
319&$319$&$319$&$319$\tabularnewline
320&$320$&$320$&$320$\tabularnewline
321&$321$&$321$&$321$\tabularnewline
322&$322$&$322$&$322$\tabularnewline
323&$323$&$323$&$323$\tabularnewline
324&$324$&$324$&$324$\tabularnewline
325&$325$&$325$&$325$\tabularnewline
326&$326$&$326$&$326$\tabularnewline
327&$327$&$327$&$327$\tabularnewline
328&$328$&$328$&$328$\tabularnewline
329&$329$&$329$&$329$\tabularnewline
330&$330$&$330$&$330$\tabularnewline
331&$331$&$331$&$331$\tabularnewline
332&$332$&$332$&$332$\tabularnewline
333&$333$&$333$&$333$\tabularnewline
334&$334$&$334$&$334$\tabularnewline
335&$335$&$335$&$335$\tabularnewline
336&$336$&$336$&$336$\tabularnewline
337&$337$&$337$&$337$\tabularnewline
338&$338$&$338$&$338$\tabularnewline
339&$339$&$339$&$339$\tabularnewline
340&$340$&$340$&$340$\tabularnewline
341&$341$&$341$&$341$\tabularnewline
342&$342$&$342$&$342$\tabularnewline
343&$343$&$343$&$343$\tabularnewline
344&$344$&$344$&$344$\tabularnewline
345&$345$&$345$&$345$\tabularnewline
346&$346$&$346$&$346$\tabularnewline
347&$347$&$347$&$347$\tabularnewline
348&$348$&$348$&$348$\tabularnewline
349&$349$&$349$&$349$\tabularnewline
350&$350$&$350$&$350$\tabularnewline
351&$351$&$351$&$351$\tabularnewline
352&$352$&$352$&$352$\tabularnewline
353&$353$&$353$&$353$\tabularnewline
354&$354$&$354$&$354$\tabularnewline
355&$355$&$355$&$355$\tabularnewline
356&$356$&$356$&$356$\tabularnewline
357&$357$&$357$&$357$\tabularnewline
358&$358$&$358$&$358$\tabularnewline
359&$359$&$359$&$359$\tabularnewline
360&$360$&$360$&$360$\tabularnewline
361&$361$&$361$&$361$\tabularnewline
362&$362$&$362$&$362$\tabularnewline
363&$363$&$363$&$363$\tabularnewline
364&$364$&$364$&$364$\tabularnewline
365&$365$&$365$&$365$\tabularnewline
366&$366$&$366$&$366$\tabularnewline
367&$367$&$367$&$367$\tabularnewline
368&$368$&$368$&$368$\tabularnewline
369&$369$&$369$&$369$\tabularnewline
370&$370$&$370$&$370$\tabularnewline
371&$371$&$371$&$371$\tabularnewline
372&$372$&$372$&$372$\tabularnewline
373&$373$&$373$&$373$\tabularnewline
374&$374$&$374$&$374$\tabularnewline
375&$375$&$375$&$375$\tabularnewline
376&$376$&$376$&$376$\tabularnewline
377&$377$&$377$&$377$\tabularnewline
378&$378$&$378$&$378$\tabularnewline
379&$379$&$379$&$379$\tabularnewline
380&$380$&$380$&$380$\tabularnewline
381&$381$&$381$&$381$\tabularnewline
382&$382$&$382$&$382$\tabularnewline
383&$383$&$383$&$383$\tabularnewline
384&$384$&$384$&$384$\tabularnewline
385&$385$&$385$&$385$\tabularnewline
386&$386$&$386$&$386$\tabularnewline
387&$387$&$387$&$387$\tabularnewline
388&$388$&$388$&$388$\tabularnewline
389&$389$&$389$&$389$\tabularnewline
390&$390$&$390$&$390$\tabularnewline
391&$391$&$391$&$391$\tabularnewline
392&$392$&$392$&$392$\tabularnewline
393&$393$&$393$&$393$\tabularnewline
394&$394$&$394$&$394$\tabularnewline
395&$395$&$395$&$395$\tabularnewline
396&$396$&$396$&$396$\tabularnewline
397&$397$&$397$&$397$\tabularnewline
398&$398$&$398$&$398$\tabularnewline
399&$399$&$399$&$399$\tabularnewline
400&$400$&$400$&$400$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{longtable}}

\hyperdef{}{section}{\subsection{section}\label{section}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd advise posting a complete minimal example here in the form of TeX code for a complete minimal document. Somebody here can then help you figure out why you are getting the issue, without having to reproduce your workflow.

Comment: longtable is always full width, in the sense you can not have anything alongside it. If you want to constrain the width of the columns as with any latex table use (for example)  `p{2cm}` instad of `c`

Comment: @cfr, you are absolutely right. I added the code I use. I hope my question is clear now.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I am not sure if you understand my question well, but I gave much more information now. Will you take a second look? thanks!

Comment: Since the default behaviour of longtable is to do what you want _no one_ could have understood your question until you showed the code that was forcing the table to be too wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
\multicolumn{4}{p{\linewidth}}{note}\tabularnewline
```

requests the full line width for the table. Since the columns would be small otherwise, the space has to go somewhere and LaTeX puts it in the last column.

There are several ways to solve the problem, e.g.:

- An additional fifth column, which takes the remaining space
- A smaller width for the note.
- Setting the note out of alignment via `\noalign{...}`.

Here an example that figures out the width of the table for use a width for the note:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}% a5paper to get a smaller image
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\LongTableWidth}{%
  \dimexpr 0pt\expandafter\LTW@parse\LT@save@row{}{}{}\relax
}
\def\LTW@parse#1#2#3{%
  \ifx\\#1#2#3\\%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    +#3%
  \fi
  \LTW@parse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lrrr}
\caption{title} \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col1}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col2}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col3}\tabularnewline
\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{\em (continued)} \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col1}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col2}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col3}\tabularnewline
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{%
  p{\dimexpr\LongTableWidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}%
}{note}\tabularnewline
\endfoot
1&$  1$&$  1$&$  1$\tabularnewline
2&$  2$&$  2$&$  2$\tabularnewline
3&$  3$&$  3$&$  3$\tabularnewline
4&$  4$&$  4$&$  4$\tabularnewline
5&$  5$&$  5$&$  5$\tabularnewline
6&$  6$&$  6$&$  6$\tabularnewline
7&$  7$&$  7$&$  7$\tabularnewline
8&$  8$&$  8$&$  8$\tabularnewline
9&$  9$&$  9$&$  9$\tabularnewline
10&$ 10$&$ 10$&$ 10$\tabularnewline
11&$ 11$&$ 11$&$ 11$\tabularnewline
12&$ 12$&$ 12$&$ 12$\tabularnewline
13&$ 13$&$ 13$&$ 13$\tabularnewline
14&$ 14$&$ 14$&$ 14$\tabularnewline
15&$ 15$&$ 15$&$ 15$\tabularnewline
16&$ 16$&$ 16$&$ 16$\tabularnewline
17&$ 17$&$ 17$&$ 17$\tabularnewline
18&$ 18$&$ 18$&$ 18$\tabularnewline
19&$ 19$&$ 19$&$ 19$\tabularnewline
20&$ 20$&$ 20$&$ 20$\tabularnewline
21&$ 21$&$ 21$&$ 21$\tabularnewline
22&$ 22$&$ 22$&$ 22$\tabularnewline
23&$ 23$&$ 23$&$ 23$\tabularnewline
24&$ 24$&$ 24$&$ 24$\tabularnewline
25&$ 25$&$ 25$&$ 25$\tabularnewline
26&$ 26$&$ 26$&$ 26$\tabularnewline
27&$ 27$&$ 27$&$ 27$\tabularnewline
28&$ 28$&$ 28$&$ 28$\tabularnewline
29&$ 29$&$ 29$&$ 29$\tabularnewline
30&$ 30$&$ 30$&$ 30$\tabularnewline
31&$ 31$&$ 31$&$ 31$\tabularnewline
32&$ 32$&$ 32$&$ 32$\tabularnewline
33&$ 33$&$ 33$&$ 33$\tabularnewline
34&$ 34$&$ 34$&$ 34$\tabularnewline
35&$ 35$&$ 35$&$ 35$\tabularnewline
36&$ 36$&$ 36$&$ 36$\tabularnewline
37&$ 37$&$ 37$&$ 37$\tabularnewline
38&$ 38$&$ 38$&$ 38$\tabularnewline
39&$ 39$&$ 39$&$ 39$\tabularnewline
40&$ 40$&$ 40$&$ 40$\tabularnewline
41&$ 41$&$ 41$&$ 41$\tabularnewline
42&$ 42$&$ 42$&$ 42$\tabularnewline
43&$ 43$&$ 43$&$ 43$\tabularnewline
44&$ 44$&$ 44$&$ 44$\tabularnewline
45&$ 45$&$ 45$&$ 45$\tabularnewline
46&$ 46$&$ 46$&$ 46$\tabularnewline
47&$ 47$&$ 47$&$ 47$\tabularnewline
48&$ 48$&$ 48$&$ 48$\tabularnewline
49&$ 49$&$ 49$&$ 49$\tabularnewline
50&$ 50$&$ 50$&$ 50$\tabularnewline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result, first page]

### Dummy column with fixed width for note

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lrrrl}% dummy column at the end
\caption{title} \tabularnewline
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col1}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col2}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col3}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{\em (continued)} \tabularnewline
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col1}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col2}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{col3}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
% \midrule
\bottomrule\noalign{\vskip\belowrulesep}
\multicolumn{5}{p{.5\linewidth}}{\lipsum[101]}\tabularnewline
\endfoot
1&$  1$&$  1$&$  1$\tabularnewline
2&$  2$&$  2$&$  2$\tabularnewline
3&$  3$&$  3$&$  3$\tabularnewline
4&$  4$&$  4$&$  4$\tabularnewline
5&$  5$&$  5$&$  5$\tabularnewline
6&$  6$&$  6$&$  6$\tabularnewline
7&$  7$&$  7$&$  7$\tabularnewline
8&$  8$&$  8$&$  8$\tabularnewline
9&$  9$&$  9$&$  9$\tabularnewline
10&$ 10$&$ 10$&$ 10$\tabularnewline
11&$ 11$&$ 11$&$ 11$\tabularnewline
12&$ 12$&$ 12$&$ 12$\tabularnewline
13&$ 13$&$ 13$&$ 13$\tabularnewline
14&$ 14$&$ 14$&$ 14$\tabularnewline
15&$ 15$&$ 15$&$ 15$\tabularnewline
16&$ 16$&$ 16$&$ 16$\tabularnewline
17&$ 17$&$ 17$&$ 17$\tabularnewline
18&$ 18$&$ 18$&$ 18$\tabularnewline
19&$ 19$&$ 19$&$ 19$\tabularnewline
20&$ 20$&$ 20$&$ 20$\tabularnewline
21&$ 21$&$ 21$&$ 21$\tabularnewline
22&$ 22$&$ 22$&$ 22$\tabularnewline
23&$ 23$&$ 23$&$ 23$\tabularnewline
24&$ 24$&$ 24$&$ 24$\tabularnewline
25&$ 25$&$ 25$&$ 25$\tabularnewline
26&$ 26$&$ 26$&$ 26$\tabularnewline
27&$ 27$&$ 27$&$ 27$\tabularnewline
28&$ 28$&$ 28$&$ 28$\tabularnewline
29&$ 29$&$ 29$&$ 29$\tabularnewline
30&$ 30$&$ 30$&$ 30$\tabularnewline
31&$ 31$&$ 31$&$ 31$\tabularnewline
32&$ 32$&$ 32$&$ 32$\tabularnewline
33&$ 33$&$ 33$&$ 33$\tabularnewline
34&$ 34$&$ 34$&$ 34$\tabularnewline
35&$ 35$&$ 35$&$ 35$\tabularnewline
36&$ 36$&$ 36$&$ 36$\tabularnewline
37&$ 37$&$ 37$&$ 37$\tabularnewline
38&$ 38$&$ 38$&$ 38$\tabularnewline
39&$ 39$&$ 39$&$ 39$\tabularnewline
40&$ 40$&$ 40$&$ 40$\tabularnewline
41&$ 41$&$ 41$&$ 41$\tabularnewline
42&$ 42$&$ 42$&$ 42$\tabularnewline
43&$ 43$&$ 43$&$ 43$\tabularnewline
44&$ 44$&$ 44$&$ 44$\tabularnewline
45&$ 45$&$ 45$&$ 45$\tabularnewline
46&$ 46$&$ 46$&$ 46$\tabularnewline
47&$ 47$&$ 47$&$ 47$\tabularnewline
48&$ 48$&$ 48$&$ 48$\tabularnewline
49&$ 49$&$ 49$&$ 49$\tabularnewline
50&$ 50$&$ 50$&$ 50$\tabularnewline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result, first page]

Comment: Thanks! How can I make the width smaller, your second solution? (Apologies,I am new to LaTeX)

Comment: @user1983395 For example, a column type `l` for `\multicolumn` can be combined with an inner `\parbox` (or `minipage`).

Comment: I replaced `p{\linewidth}` with `p{6cm}` and my poblem seems solved.